# Cancelling GWT RPC Request : Design

Tags: gwt

I changed the client facing Aysnc interface to return Request instead of void. Using the Request handle I can cancel the requests that aren't required anymore on browser. The problem is that every time a developer uses this async interface, he has to remember that Request object from the RPC call has to be added to a singleton tracking class.

Is there a way to centralize this so that every time a RPC call is made, the Request object is stored ? I looked at the http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html, but I couldn't still figure out how to do this.

Comment: You can also ask GWT questions from GWT developers here: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt